# Get AWS CloundFront Invalidations usage (last month)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS Cloudfront Java SDK to automate some tasks, one of those is to invalidate distributions. I have read that the first 1000 invalidation requests (paths actually) are free, after that they [are billed](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/).

I don't see any functionality in the [SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront/AmazonCloudFrontClient.html) to get the total number of invlidation requests executed in the last month for the account (not the distribution). Is there any way to get it?

If there is no way to get it using the SDK, i think that i will create a local record of the invalidation requests usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get this in the SDK, however, you can monitor CloudFront Invalidations in CloudTrail and get the data you need there.

I would post a code sample, however, while AWS is firmly in my skillset, JAVA is not.  Nonetheless, I checked the JAVA SDK and it appears that the methods to accomplish this are available.  At a high level, you will enable CloudTrail on your account, and then use the [lookupEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudtrail/AbstractAWSCloudTrail.html#lookupEvents--) method of the CloudTrail API in the JAVA SDK to find events named `CreateInvalidation`.

Although its not a direct example in JAVA, you can also do this from the CLI:

`aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=CreateInvalidation`

Which will return an array of events:

```
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "EventId": "9a999999-9999-9aaa-aa99-a9999a9aa9aa",
            "EventName": "CreateInvalidation",
            "ReadOnly": "false",
            "AccessKeyId": "ASXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "EventTime": 1566438448.0,
            "EventSource": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
            "Username": "user.name",
            "Resources": [],
            "CloudTrailEvent": "{FULL-CLOUDTRAIL-EVENT-DATA-HERE}"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see each event has a timestamp, `EventTime`.  Iterate over the array, check if the timestamp is in your required time range, if it's outside of your time range you can simply remove it from the array and then when that's done simply count the remaining items in the array.

Note that the API responses may be paginated, so you'll have to watch for a `NextToken` in the response which indicates there are more events to be fetched.

**EDIT:** Also, it's worth noting that CloudFront is a Global service. As a global service CloudFront events are logged in CloudTrail in the `us-east-1` region ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging_using_cloudtrail.html)).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exposed through an API.

You can find it in the [Cost & Usage Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage-details.html).

Remember that invalidation requests support wildcards, so it's often possible to invalidate everything you need with a single request and a single path.  You may invalidate more than you need using this approach, but that is sometimes an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using the Cost & Usage report for this... Interesting approach.

Comment: Thank you! this was useful, i was able to find the number of invalidations for a period of time by filtering the "Cost & Usage Report" (AWS console) by service="CloudFront" and usageType="Invalidations".